# Converts html to docx with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I would like to convert my html report to docx. I put 2 images side by side on my docx page.

For my first try, I just use this html below and I can achieve what I need:

```html
<div>
      <img width="256px" height="256px" src="imga1.png"/>
      <!-- I use this to simulate margin-right -->
     <span>&emsp;</span><span>&emsp;</span><span>&emsp;</span><span>&emsp; 
      </span>
      <img width="256px" height="256px" src="image2.png"/>
  <div>
```

Now I would like to add a header for each image and that creates complication.

As an assumption, my first text header will not exceed 256px (because it is the image's size). And 256px corresponds to 16 "&emsp".

Then I compute my text header image by using a canvas 2d context method in javascript (text metrics).

After that I substract 256px by my computed text width and compute the number of "&emsp" that I need to fit the first image.

With this method, I can put my header for my 2 images but it is not efficient because my text second header image is not always aligned to the second image.

I am looking methods to put my image header all aligned to images.

Comment: I wouldn't do layouting with spaces... can't you just put the image in a [reference doc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc) ?

Comment: After creating custom-reference.docx with this command "pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx", I do not know how to use this custom-reference. Furthermore my images are dynamically added